# how to redirect www.xyz.com/[product_id] to [prouduct_id].abc.com? Example : suppose product_id = 23 so, www.xyz.com/23 should redirect to 23.abc.com

Tags: php, html, redirect, web

how to redirect

```
www.xyz.com/[product_id]
```

to [`prouduct_id].abc.com?`  Example : 
suppose product_id = 23 so, 
**www.xyz.com/23** 
should redirect to 
**23.abc.com**

I'v tried PHP Redirection but it's failing :

```
<?php
    $link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $link_array = explode('/',$link);

    $page = components[2];    $page = end($link_array);
$url = $page.".abc.com";
    header("location://$url");
?>
```

PHP Redirection problem detail :
 www.xyz.com/23 = No Page Found.
but, when I try to visit normally, `www.xyz.com` it takes me to `index.php.abc.com` And,
when I try to visit `www.xyz.com/index.php/23` the it takes me to the right place i.e. `23.abc.com` but I want `www.xyz.com/23` should redirect to `23.abc.com` without getting Page not found error and normal visit to page www.xyz.com should also not get affected.

Comment: looking for sub domain ?

Comment: This can be done by apache.conf or .htaccess directives. or even with javascript....

Comment: can you please tell the script for that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I'v tried PHP Redirection but it's failing" Does it display an error? Or does it redirect to the wrong place or not redirect at all?

Comment: I've added the problem which PHP redirection is giving. @dorukayhan

Answer (score 0):

In `.htaccess`, try using the following code to redirect from `xyz.com/[product_id]` to `xyz.com/index.php/[product_id]`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1
```

Your PHP redirection code should work now using `xyz.com/[product_id]`

Comment: @Condorce It gives "Internal Server Error! Contact Server Admin".
I checked the server error log it shows this : 
` [Thu Mar 30 19:40:53.006353 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1034] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Mar 30 19:40:53.008004 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1034] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
`
[

Comment: The sites use `https`? Seems like an error with the certificate.